# BIRT decimal precision

Tags: formatting, birt

I'm trying to output decimal numbers in format with 2 digits after dot (for example, to output *0* as *0.00*). I've tried:

```
dataSetRow["Joint TariffCodePT Data Set::MySQL Data Set::sum_rcosht"].toFixed(2)
```

and

```
BirtMath.round(dataSetRow["Joint TariffCodePT Data Set::MySQL Data Set::sum_rcosht"], 2).toFixed(2)
```

and

```
Formatter.format(dataSetRow["Joint TariffCodePT Data Set::MySQL Data Set::sum_rcosht"], "0.00")
```

But nothing is working, *0* is outputted as *0*.

Data type is Decimal:

[image]

And Preview Result is outputted with 2 digits after dot :

[image]

What is the reason of problem and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the number in decimal places in data binding, you can follow the below mentioned steps ( from expression remove Birt.Math function, only dataset row can be placed in expression. Formatting number can be done by following below mentioned steps)

1. Select the data binding column, Goto Layout=> Property Editor - Data=>Properties=> Format Number=> Select **Format as** Currency from drop down ( Under Currency setting in same tab, set decimal places "2 as in your case". Disable 1000 separator if not required)

[Formatting Number in decimal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/45FmD.jpg)